# HDMI stops working after some time on bionic (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, hdmi, external-monitor

I currently have a Dell Latitude 7400 with the following specs running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS:

RAM 15.4 GiB

Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-8665U CPU @ 1.90GHz × 8

Graphics: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2)

GNOME: 3.28.2

The HDMI signal to the external monitor stops suddenly while the laptop is in use or after the laptops wakes up from sleep.

> **xrandr** does not detect any external monitor once the HDMI signal dies. The monitor just displays no HDMI signal detected.

A reboot of the laptop enables the monitor to detect the HDMI signal again.

Is there a way to reset the HDMI signal without rebooting the laptop each time the HDMI signal dies?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this worked. By simply running in a terminal

`lspci --nk | grep -iA3 vga`

sprung the HDMI signal back to life and the external monitor could detect the HDMI signal again :-)